# Saving newlines in text file in Java

Tags: java

I want to save a text in a text file and I need to save the \n character to delimit the elements in the text. The text is as follow:

"This is a java prog. and It saves text in a .txt file.

You can choose where it should be saved."

How I can save \n (newline) in a .txt file?

The follow is the code segment I used to save text in text file:

```
FileOutputStream fout = null;

try {

    fout = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    System.out.println("output File not found");
    return false;
}

Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    fout.write((sc.next().getBytes()));
}

fout.close();
```

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is

Comment: Do you mean you want to save `\n` in your file as text in your text file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
  fout.write((sc.next().getBytes()));
  fout.write("\n".getBytes());
}
```

this will write the line you entered into the standard input, then write a newline, so that the file will be separated by newlines

Comment: I am not sure what he wanted. OPs question is kinda confusing.

Comment: I figured the "\n character" refered to a newline, as the literal "\n" (a slash followed by an n) is two characters.  but this is easily adaptable to also put the literal "\n" by changing `"\n".getBytes()` to `"\\n".getBytes()`

Comment: So My answer was right if he wants to put `\n` as text in text file.

Comment: Peter, unfortunately it didn't work. Your statement didn't make any changes.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clear that both of the fout.write commands go inside of the while loop, in case that might be the issue.  the other issue is if you are opening the final text file in a Windows editor like Notepad, you might not see the entries on separate lines.  If you want it to be readable in Notepad, change `"\n"` to `"\r\n"` in my code sample

Comment: Peter, please tell me why it needs \r for notepad?

Comment: \r\n (which is a "Carriage Return" followed by a "Line Feed") was used in old teleprinter machines, got carried over to old mainframe OSes and was incorporated into DOS and eventually windows.  Unix machines just used a Line Feed character ("\n") to keep things simpler.  The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) provides a pretty full explaination of how this came to be.

Comment: @zari Sorry for the misinterpretation. I should have used he/she. I was confused about your requirement that you need line feed for next line or as text.

Comment: Oh no problem! I need for next line.